# JS: Checking if no children exist not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have a text input box that when you press keys on the keyboard it shows the ASCII codes underneath in a list. 
When you first click on the box the paragraph above is hidden. When you click away from the box I want the paragraph to reappear only if there is no list of codes underneath (nothing has been pressed or everything has been deleted).
I'm trying to check the list with "if (element.childNodes.length == 0)" but it's not working. 
Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id='press'>Press a key on the keyboard in the input field to get the Unicode character code of the pressed key.</p>

<input id="text" type="text" size=40 onkeypress="myFunction(event)" onkeydown="downFunction(event)">

<script>

function myFunction(event) {
  var x = event.which || event.keyCode || event.charCode;
    if(x >= 65 && x <= 90 || x >= 97 && x <= 122 || x == 32){ 
      var element  = document.getElementById('ul');
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = String.fromCharCode(x) + ': ' + x;
    fragment.appendChild(li);
    element.appendChild(fragment);
        };
};

function downFunction(event) {
  var y = event.which || event.keyCode || event.charCode;
    if( y == 8 ){
      var element  = document.getElementById('ul');
      element.removeChild(element.lastChild);
};
};

$('#text').click(function(e){
  $('#press').hide();
    });
    
$('#text').focusout(function(e){
  var element  = document.getElementById('ul');
      if (element.childNodes.length == 0) {
        $('#press').show();
      };
    });

</script>

<ul id="ul">
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work as expected is because you're using [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes), which counts all child nodes of an element, including plain text. While there may not be any elements in your `#ul`, there is a text node. Note that:

```
<ul id = "ul">
</ul>
```

is differrent from:

```
<ul id = "ul"></ul>
```

To remedy your issue, use [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) instead, which returns an element-only collection that won't be affected by how you space your HTML code. The difference can be seen in the following snippet.

**Snippet:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
var ul1 = document.getElementById("ul1");
var ul2 = document.getElementById("ul2");

console.log("ul1.childNodes: " + ul1.childNodes.length);
console.log("ul1.children: " + ul1.children.length);
console.log("ul2.childNodes: " + ul2.childNodes.length);
console.log("ul2.children: " + ul2.children.length);
```

```html
<!------ HTML ----->
<ul id = "ul1">
</ul>

<ul id = "ul2"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your condition as below:

```
element.childNodes.length === 0 || 
(element.childNodes.length === 1 && !element.childNodes[0].tagName)
```

By this, you can control if a child is an actual dom node with a tagName